# "score some puff" meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading a play by Joe Penhall. I am not able to get the meaning of this conversation:

> ***Christopher:***  He smokes too much drugs, man, d'you know what I mean? he likes his puff.  I can tell.
>   *(silence)*
>   ***Robert:*** Sorry... you said? About ... Dr...?
>   ***Christopher:*** He told me I should go back out there and score some puff, man. Why did he say that? because I'm black?

What is Christopher talking about? Especially by these two sentences: "He likes his puff" and "I should go back out there and score some puff".

Comment: Puff = puff of smoke => he likes smoking. Which is what he does with his drugs.

Comment: .. and *score* is slang for *acquire*

Comment: Is it just me, I wonder, but what puff means can be understood quite clearly from the context and the meaning of "to score" can be looked up on any online dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puff) doesn't have this meaning of *puff,* but OED does.

> **1. i.** *Brit. slang.* Marijuana.
>
> > 1989   K. Smith *Inside Time* 235   Puff, cannabis.
> > 1992   R. Graef *Living Dangerously* v. 138   I'm not into drugs: just puff, trips, that's about it.
> > 2002   C. Newland *Snakeskin* ix. 112   She was paranoid bad about her dad finding out she smoked puff.

ODO **does** have [*score*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/score):

> **1.6** *informal* Buy or acquire (something, typically illegal drugs):
> *Sally had scored some acid*